# Python: importing from 1+ levels down

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, import

Say that I import with the unnecessarily long full path:

```
from pandas.core.series import Series
```

The more common import is simply:

```
from pandas import Series
```

to which I can view the full path with:

```
Series
Out[6]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Here is the source of my confusion.  Nowhere in the top-level [`__init__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py) module is there any import of `from core import *` (or `core.series`, for that matter).  The `__init__` module for `.core` is empty also.

**What enables me to be able to use simply `from pandas import Series` rather than the full path or, more generally, to import a module, function, variable, or class that is "several levels down"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [inside the `__init__.py` file](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py#L42):

```
from pandas.core.api import *
```

in which [`Series` is imported](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/api.py#L22).

Comment: Oh okay i see.  So does `core.api` exist solely for that purpose?  (Basically serving as an intermediary between the two imports.)  I noticed that `core.series` defines `__all__ = ['Series']`.  Why not just import more directly?

Comment: Definitely seems like it. Either that or there's some historical reason behind the decision to organize it in this fashion.